# .htaccess mod_rewrite: rewriting querystring to path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How could I use a rewrite to change:

/?tag=foo

To:

/tag/foo

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tag=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/tag/$1 [L]
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid recursion, you should check the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) instead as the query string in `%{QUERY_STRING}` may already have been changed by another rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\?(([^&\s]*&)*)tag=([^&\s]+)&?([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tag/%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]
```

Then you can rewrite that requests back internally without conflicts:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*) index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Andrew Moore and Gumbo

Thank you, but thank you very much.

I'm trying to a solution to more than one week without success.

The solution presented by Gumbo resolve the problem.

When meeting people willing to help others who do not know I am sure that we can have a better world.

Sorry errors, but my knowledge of English is very limited.

I just want to thank.

Vera

Comment: You solved my problem when all other stackoverflow answers on similar posts could not. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tag=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/tag/%1 [L]
```

Usually, rewrites are used to achieve the opposite effect. Are you sure you don't really want to do the following?

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.+)$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to convert from a URL like this:

```
http://java.scandilabs.com/faq?key=Contents_of__gitigno
```

To a URL like this:

```
http://scandilabs.com/technology/knowledge/Contents_of__gitigno
```

Andrew's response above worked for me with the addition of a question mark at the end to discard the original query string:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^java
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=(.+)$    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://scandilabs.com/technology/knowledge/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Note if you're on apache 2.4 or higher you can probably use the QSD flag instead of the question mark.