# Using RewriteRules on query strings from root of domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite the URLs on my site (to improve SEO, its an AJAX site) so that they go from

`http://www.domain.co.uk/?section=home`

`http://www.domain.co.uk/?section=contact`

to

`http://www.domain.co.uk/home`

`http://www.domain.co.uk/contact`

respectively.

This is my first time using .htaccess for rewriting, and I'm finding that I end up just guessing with my expressions/copying answers from other questions and trying to make them work.

The closest I've gotten is from adapting this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217981/htaccess-mod-rewrite-rewriting-querystring-to-path)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\?(([^&\s]*&)*)section=([^&\s]+)&?([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /section/%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^section/(.*) index.php?section=$1 [L]
```

which gives me the result

`http://www.domain.co.uk/section/contact`

however this also breaks all my other links, and leaves the site without CSS or javascript etc.

Furthermore, one of the sections of my site has URLs that look like this

`http://www.domain.co.uk/?section=blog&post=post-name-one`

`http://www.domain.co.uk/?section=blog&post=post-name-two`

which I wanted to rewrite to

`http://www.domain.co.uk/blog/post-name-one`

`http://www.domain.co.uk/blog/post-name-two`

However, I'm am very unsure about how to approach this in RegEx.

Could anyone help in getting this right? If there are good references for writing these rules, I'd be happy to hear about them as well. So far the things I have read have been helpful in explaining what is happening, but I haven't been able to write my own yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?section=([^\s&]+)&post=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?section=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?section=$1&post=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?section=$1 [L,QSA]
```